# Jasmine: Testing a function that uses a browser object

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test this function with Jasmine:

```
myFunc: function () {
  var name = document.getElementById("bob");
  display.innerHTML = name;
  return 100;
}
```

The test fails with `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. I understand that I'm not running the test in a browser so document isn't defined. But how come mocking it out isn't working? Is there a way to write this test with standalone Jasmine only?

How would one generally go about testing these kinds of functions (JavaScript mixed with DOM)? I'd prefer not to use another library/framework.

```
// Mock, stub dom object.
var document;
  beforeEach(function () {
  document = jasmine.createSpyObj('document', ['getElementById', 'createElement']);
});

describe("myFunc", function () {    
  it("return 100", function () {
    console.log(document);         // My mock document object successfully logs.
    expect(myFunc()).toEqual(100); // but document isn't defined in here.
  });
});
```

Comment: As you said, you are not running the tests in a browser, so I guess you are using `jasmine-node` or something like that, which runs the tests in Node.js environment, right?

Comment: I am just using jasmine installed via npm. I have a spec folder and run my tests via 'jasmine' command in my project root.

Comment: In Node.js environment there is no global object `document`, it is available only in browser environment. Yes, you can create a spy to replace it, but you have to make it global for your unit under test.